# How do you use gnuplot's built-in fonts?

Tags: gnuplot

The gnuplot docs have this to say about fonts:

```
    Five basic fonts are supported directly by the gd library. These are
    `tiny` (5x8 pixels), `small` (6x12 pixels), `medium`, (7x13 Bold), 
    `large` (8x16) or `giant` (9x15 pixels).
```

But when i try to use one:

```
    gnuplot> set terminal png font tiny
```

I get:

```
    Could not find/open font when opening font tiny, using default
```

How do I use these seemingly built-in fonts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that, for these fonts for some reason, you don't use the standard syntax I tried above:

```
gnuplot> set terminal png font tiny
```

But instead, you drop the word "font" for these five special fonts:

```
gnuplot> set terminal png tiny
```